# Installed module using pip, not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pythonpath

I am trying to install a package called "simpleguitk" via pip. (On Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5)
After running

```
sudo -H pip3 install simpleguitk
```

it says installation is completed successfully. (Except for the pygame dependecy which is actually optional)

```
Collecting simpleguitk
Using cached SimpleGUITk-1.1.3.tar.gz
Collecting Pillow>=2.0.0 (from simpleguitk)
Using cached Pillow-3.4.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pygame>=1.9.0 (from simpleguitk)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame>=1.9.0 (from simpleguitk) (from versions: 1.9.2.dev1, 1.9.2b7, 1.9.2b8)
No matching distribution found for pygame>=1.9.0 (from simpleguitk)
```

I cannot find the package at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
or /usr/lib/python3.5 or /usr/lib/python3

When I try to import the module it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'simpleguitk'
```

I tried to reinstall it, but running:

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall simpleguitk
```

returns: "Cannot uninstall requirement simpleguitk, not installed
"

I have tried this on both pip 8.1.2 and pip 9.0.1 with the same results.
I have even reinstalled Ubuntu, but still the same.

I think Python Path is wrong as it does not have python 3.5 but I do not know how to fix it

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

Comment: What does `~/.pip.log` says ?

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you're installing it for the version of python you're using, with

```
/path/to/your/python -m pip install <package>
```

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install cassandra-driver` worked for me, but `pip3 install cassandra-driver` did not. What's the difference between the two statements?

Answer (score 9):

`pip` needs `python`, and sometimes the `python` you are trying to execute your `*.py` may not be same as the `python` binary used by `pip`.

Can you retry installing following these steps:

`which python`

Let's say it prints:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Means you can use:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install <package>
```

Or you can try to choose from the different versions you have of python.

Now try executing you `*.py` using

`/usr/bin/python  *.py`

Comment: Is it possible you meant "which python" ?

Comment: I did mean 'which python' and not 'which bin'

Comment: you need `python -m pip`

Comment: pip is a module of python, which is why you need the "-m" to run the module, just running python pip makes your interpreter think that "pip" is a path for a script it needs to run, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The module may be installed but the program doesn't run. This happens because of 2 different versions of python co-existing. So run your Py Script with the location of the python version you have installed the module for, say `usr/bin/python python.py` or `/usr/bin/python3 python.py`.

Hope this helps in your progress!

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that the version of python you used to install the module does not match the version python you are trying to import from.

1. Find out whether the module in the python version you wanted 
   you can try using the command: `pip3 freeze` to get the list of packages installed for version of python(In your case, it is python3.5).
2. Before that, check different versions of python installed in your machine. You can use the command `locate /python | grep /bin`
   if you have python2.7 and python3.5, then you should use the corresponding pip/pip3 to install the modules.
3. Open the corresponding python shell (python3) and try to import again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with PyCharm, where the dependencies I installed using pip would work for the editor windows (i.e., there were no error reports about imports), but the project would complain about the dependencies when I tried to run it. Turns out, I set up a virtual environment for that project **after** I created the tasks that ran my project and tests. I had to go to the window where you set up the tasks and make sure that all of them used the correct venv.
Hope this is useful.