# Python with Pushover: No module named pushover

Tags: python, python-3.x, pushover

I tested a python script to send anythink with Pushover. But I get the error "ImportError: No module named pushover"

My installed Versions:

```
# pip install python-pushover
Collecting python-pushover
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/3d/144a0137c749bd152c3ab7f4d3ce8fe1455168dab36c2fcd900d3fab16ad/python-pushover-0.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from python-pushover) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushover) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushover) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushover) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushover) (2.8)
Installing collected packages: python-pushover
  Running setup.py install for python-pushover ... done
Successfully installed python-pushover-0.4
# python -V
Python 2.7.13
# python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
```

The scriptheader:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pushover
```

I have tried with pip(3) to install python-pushover but with no success.

Comment: it is recommended to use virtualenv to be safe from these kind of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this exact error today. This is due to co-existing of different versions of python in your system.

Do, `/usr/bin/python3` if the module was installed for py3 and just `/usr/bin/python` for py2 before running the script.

Refer [Installed module using pip, not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834656/installed-module-using-pip-not-found/53754963#53754963) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you should :

**uninstall that package:**

```
pip uninstall pushover
```

**and install the correct package:**

```
pip install python-pushover
```

And your code will work fine.

Comment: Its the same error.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./notify_pushover.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pushover
ImportError: No module named pushover

Comment: hmm , let me check again

Comment: execuse me, what python version you are using ?

Comment: Thank you. My testscript: https://github.com/sriccio/zabbix-alertscripts/blob/master/notify_pushover.py

Comment: I have write in first post: Debian Stretch with Python 2.7.13 and Python 3.5.3

Comment: Run ```which pip``` and make sure you are running on same one. Not conda or other envs tricks

Comment: which pip: /usr/local/bin/pip. I have try /usr/local/bin/pip install python-pushover with the same error. Pushover is here: /usr/local/bin/pushover