# Jupyter notebook does not find a package

Tags: python, github, module, jupyter

I have a library that I've imported and have used within PyCharm with no problem. However, I would like to work with this repository within a Jupyter notebook for ease of debugging (my Pycharm has a mysterious bug on its debugger...). I keep getting "No module named 'ListManagement". How do I install this github repository so I can use it in Jupyter. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got different versions of python installed in your system. Do, /usr/bin/python3 if the module was installed for py3 and just /usr/bin/python for py2 before running the script.

Refer the [Installed module using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834656/installed-module-using-pip-not-found/53754963#53754963), not found for more.

Comment: I just realized the repository is a private one. I don't know why PyCharm has no issue with importing it but Jupyter does. Importing it woudln't work either since it's a private github repostory, correct? So first, I'd have to make it public first?

Comment: I dont think bring a 'private repository' is causing the problem. However, you can try to make it public just to make sure, the problem lies there