# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplejson'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ pip3 install simplejson
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (3.17.2)
    
$ python3 -V
Python 3.9.6
```

Since `simplejson` is already installed why can't the 3.9.6 version of Python use it?

Comment: how do you know python 3.9.6 can't use simplejson?

Comment: Because I keep getting a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplejson'"

Comment: Your `pip3` is for Python 3.8. Look at where it installed simplejson: "simplejson in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages". You have to make sure to install the package in the same Python you use to run your app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installed module using pip, not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834656/installed-module-using-pip-not-found)

Comment: @GinoMempin Yep, that did it, thanks!

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834656/installed-module-using-pip-not-found