# Why - after checking the python path - it still can't find my module?

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, importerror

I’m having difficulty getting Python to find my pip installation of the module `romodel`. Here’s what I’ve done so far:

1. Checked what my python path is using `which python`:

   `/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`
2. Used that to install using pip: `/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install romodel`
3. Uninstalled the existing one (which probably didn’t change anything): `pip3 uninstall romodel`
4. Started `python`, and tried to find the romodel package:

   ```
   import romodel 

   Traceback (most recent call last): 

     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'romodel'
   ```
5. I made sure that the `romodel` install location is in the path:

   `ls /Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ |grep "romodel"`

   `romodel-0.0.1.dist-info`
6. So, I start `python` and manually add the package location to the path:

   `import sys`

   `sys.path.append('/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/')`
7. However, still no module found:

   ```
   import romodel 

   Traceback (most recent call last): 

     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'romodel'
   ```

Is there something obvious that I’m missing?
Based on the resources listed below, I would have expected the above procedure to work.

I used the following resources:

- https://realpython.com/lessons/why-cant-python-find-my-modules/
- [Installed module using pip, not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834656/installed-module-using-pip-not-found)

And my own previous question: [How to correctly uninstall numpy on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187374/how-to-correctly-uninstall-numpy-on-macosx)

Comment: You uninstalled the package in step 3 and never installed it again (assuming `pip3` is part of the Anaconda installation as well).

Comment: I suppose I forgot to include that, but yes I re-installed it using `pip3 install romodel`.  This should go between steps 3 and 4.  But anyway, step 5 shows that the directory is still there regardless.

Comment: That fact that *only* the `dist-info` directory is there, rather than a directory named `romodel` or a file named `romodel.py`, is suspicious. That directory only holds *metadata  about* (I think) the distribution package, not the Python package itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the instructions here: https://pypi.org/project/romodel/, I was mistakenly trying to install `romodel` via `pip install romodel`.  As of May 2022, that isn't how one should install romodel.

However, the correct way to install `romodel` is to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/cog-imperial/romodel:

`pip install git+https://github.com/cog-imperial/romodel.git`