# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywebio'

Tags: python

I try make small webpage quis, and considered using pywebio. But after i finish the instalation and try use it the module not found. I already check using pip list the module pywebio 1.6.1 has installed. Why this can be happen? Please somebody help me.
Thanks

The problem show like this:
File "c:\Users\richa\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pywebio\online_test.py", line 1, in 
from pywebio.input import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywebio'

Comment: `pip3 install -U pywebio`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834656/installed-module-using-pip-not-found

Comment: Still doesn't work. I already do this, and when i try import the module, find same eror.